# Is there a way to convert a list to aligned columns/grid by F-String?

Tags: python

How I can convert a single list to align columns/grid via f-string code? I know that this would be possible via certain packages, but I am only allowed to use f-string.

I have a list consisting of several items. For example:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['1','2','3','4','5'], ['1', '3', '331', '1', '82']
```

Is there a way to make it look like a grid of aligned columns like this:

```
a b   c d  e
1 2   3 4  5
1 3 331 1 82
```

Comment: Please don't use images for input/output as they are hard to reproduce locally.

Comment: Would love to hear more where you got stuck in your attempt :)

Comment: @Ch3steR Hi, I am sorry.  I am new to this forum and am not aware how I can show the output I want.

Comment: @rafaelc to be honest, I am not too sure how to get started here. I have been taught to manipute it if there are multiple lists, but it being a single list here, the solution isnt coming to me

Comment: You don't have a single list here. You have many lists. See how you have many starting and ending brackets? (`[` and `]`). Each is a list. By having many defined like that means you have all of them in one tuple. Start by iterating over your tuple and printing what you see. Then, iterate again in the inner list, and see what you see. Investigate further and come back with a clearer question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is particularized to your example tuple but it does utilize f-strings:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['1','2','3','4','5'], ['1', '3', '331', '1', '82']

for item in lst:
    print(f'{item[0]:>2}{item[1]:>2}{item[2]:>4}{item[3]:>2}{item[4]:>3}')
```

Output:

```
a b   c d  e
1 2   3 4  5
1 3 331 1 82
```

[This](http://cissandbox.bentley.edu/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2022-02-10-Documentation-on-f-strings-Updated.pdf) might prove illustrative.